# Differentiable Partial Derivatives implies equality of second partials

Tags: analysis

Assume that the first partial derivatives $f_x,f_y$ both exist and are differentiable at a neighborhood of the point $(x_0,y_0)$, we w.t.s. that the second partial derivatives are equal, i.e. $f_{yx}=f_{xy}$. Note that the continuity of $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ is not given in the question, hence this question differs the common theorem that utilizes that fact. A solution can be obtained by considering the quantity $$A=f(x+h,y+k)-f(x,y+k)-f(x+h,y)+f(x,y)$$ and then the mean value theorem for $\psi(y)=f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)$, so this question HAS a solution.

Comment: There's no proof because it's not true. Only if the second partial derivatives are continuous can we guarantee this.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos I think a proof is available if f_x, f_y are differentiable at a neighborhood. If you still don't think that is true, you should give a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

We first consider the quantity $$A=f(x+h,y+k)-f(x,y+k),-f(x+h,y)+f(x,y),$$ then let $$g(y)=f(x+h,y)-f(x,y),$$ By the mean value theorem, we have
$$\frac{A}{hk}=\frac{g(y+k)-g(y)}{hk}=\frac{g'(y+ek)}{h}=\frac{f_y(x+h,y+ek)-f_y(x,y+ek)}{h},$$ with $0<e<1$. Now since $f_y$ is differentiable at $(x,y)$, we obtain $$f_y(x+h,y+ek)=f_y(x,y)+f_{yx}(x,y)h+f_{yy}(x,y)ek+\epsilon_1\sqrt{h^2+e^2k^2}, $$ where $\epsilon_1$ tends to $0$ as $(h,k)$ tends to $0$, implying the existence of $f_{yx}$. Setting $h=0$ we find $$f_y(x,y+ek)=f_y(x,y)+f_{yy}(x,y)ek+\epsilon_2ek,$$ plugging these into the third equation, we find $$\frac{A}{hk}=\frac{f_{yx}(x,y)h+\epsilon_1\sqrt{h^2+e^2k^2}-\epsilon_2ek}{h}.$$ Taking the limit along $h=k$ to $(0,0)$ yields $$\lim_{h=k,h\to 0} \frac{A}{hk}=f_{yx}.$$ Similarly we have the same limit equal to $f_{xy}$, hence completing the proof.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is just by using the definition of derivatives and doing a little bit of algebra. Here's a link to a wiki which has a proof

https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_theorem_on_equality_of_mixed_partials

Comment: yeah but no.....the link you give uses the continuity of the second partials, which is different from the hypothesis that I gave, so maybe read the question thoroughly before giving it a downvote?

Comment: The theorem needs continuity. As the page links to two examples where the theorem fails, one when one or more mixed partial is not continuous. You don't have the result without it. Also, I never gave you a downvote.